# how to write the unit test in Jasmine for simple if condition

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm new to writing Unit testing. Please help me to write UT fot the below code

Code:

```
function setSelectedGender(selectedGender) {
    if (selectedGender) {
        test.details.Gender = selectedGender;
    }
}
```

UT: In the "it" block

```
it("should call setSelectedGender", function () {
    spyOn(controller, 'setSelectedGender').and.callThrough();
    var value = controller.setSelectedGender("Male");
    //how do I validate the if condition and compare it 
});
```

Comment: To check for variable, you can use   `expect(var).toBeDefined()` and ` `expect(var).toEqual(valueToCompare)`

Comment: I think the spyOn is wrong, As per the test the setSelectedGender should be methord of controller as (controller.setSelectedGender()) and the you are doing callThrough(), so the function really wont get called and the inner code wont work, you dont have to do this spyOn, if you share entire controller function code (not exact) then it will easy to show you a sample test case.